# Merge csv data into html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I run a html with javascript locally on my computer without a web server. Since, I dont user a webserver, I am unable to open a csv file on the local computer due to CORS restriction.

In my index.html. there is this sample code that reads data from a csv file.

```
// Get the data
d3.csv(dataCSV, function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
        d.open = +d.open;
    });
```

Here is a sample of the dataCSV file.

```
date,close,open
1-May-12,58.13,3.41
30-Apr-12,53.98,4.55
27-Apr-12,67.00,6.78
```

I would like to hardcode the csv data into the index.html, and get the data into the "d" object?
Here's a pseudocode i would like it to work.

```
<script>
data = {
    date,close,open
    1-May-12,58.13,3.41
    30-Apr-12,53.98,4.55
    27-Apr-12,67.00,6.78
};

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
    d.open = +d.open;
});
```

I tried the following, but i got the following error "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number*" on the "    *1-May-12,58.13,3.41*"

Any pointer would greatly appreciated.

2nd issue:
I was trying to perform the following graph plot with csv on local computer but I get CORS error. The 1st reply does solve the issue with importing csv for me. But, now, when I ran the code, i get the following error:

> d3.min.js:1 Error:  attribute d: Expected number,
> "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…".

Here is the base code that I was trying to emulate locally on my PC without web server. https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/e34791a32a54e015f57d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're need to change your `data={...}` to a string and parse the CSV in JavaScript, the code below should be what you were trying to accomplish.

```js
const data = `date,close,open
1-May-12,58.13,3.41
30-Apr-12,53.98,4.55
27-Apr-12,67.00,6.78`;
const lines = data.split('\n');

const keys = lines.shift().split(',');
const entries = [];

for (const line of lines) {
  const index = entries.length;
  entries[index] = {};

  const values = line.split(',');
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    entries[index][keys[i]] = values[i];
  }
}

console.log(entries);
```